# Spring boot with mongoDb like Firebase or Realtime Server app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, web-services, spring-mvc

Hello i working on project and i dont now how to start, I will be have a frontend server(spring boot) and mongoDb for database and frontend apps reactjs for web and android app for mobile. i would like to have server like "firebase realtime sync data for client", what in  wont when someone send post pust request from mobile to my server i would like to show this post data on react app, or when someone change data on react app this data will be changed on other deskop (somethink like notes List). is there a way how i cant start how to create firebase logic ... i just cant use firebase for the some reason.

Answer (score 0):

To implement a "realtime database" like Firebase you will need to use the "websocket" technical. your reacjs client will open the websocket and the server will push any db update to the listening websockets.
from client side you will have to implement your own cache (because firebase client sdk use cache) and implement the REST request.
From server side you will have to develop the rest api. The db Collections structure may be different from firebase, and the way you query them with springboot also.
The secuity data access will have to be redesigned as well.
the a lot of work, but interresting.